# Extract Hashtags and add to new csv field in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

Every month, I download twitter analytics for some work related handles that I am responsible for.

I do some data massaging in powershell (changing -'s to nulls for number columns) so that my Excel Power Query can work with the data easily.

I've decided I wanted to copy the hashtags out of the Tweet Text column into their own column for some investigation as to how they perform.

My entire script:

```
Remove-Item -path .\merged\merged.csv
$InputFiles = Get-Item "*.csv"
$OldString  = '"-"'
$NewString  = '""'
$InputFiles | ForEach {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv .\merged\merged.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Since I recognize I might have to do multiple months at once, I decided to simply redo the merged file each month.

I'm looking at what I need to add to pull out the hashtags and I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track with:

```
Import-Csv .\merged\merged.csv | Select-Object *,@{Name='hashtags';Expression={'XYZZY'}} | Export-Csv file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Of course, the trouble is I'm not sure what I need to put in XYZZY. I know my regex is #[a-zA-Z0-9] (I've had trouble getting #\w to capture anything beyond the first letter of the hashtag in some of my previous attempts.

'Tweet text' is the column name.

Tweets range anywhere from 0 to 6 hashtags. One problem I see is that every regex matches option seems to return items in an object where I'm hoping to simply add them as a space delimited list in that final field.

Questions I might see coming up:
Why not do this in Excel?
Good question. I initially wanted to add it to the power query import, but it doesn't actually seem to be possible. While I could do it in VBA, I'd rather this be packagable as a solution.

Why not do this in Python?
I do have a solution mostly done, but I'd really like to keep this as a simple process.

What are the headers?
"Tweet id","Tweet permalink","Tweet text","time","impressions","engagements","engagement rate","retweets","replies","likes","user profile clicks","url clicks","hashtag clicks","detail expands","permalink clicks","app opens","app installs","follows","email tweet","dial phone","media views","media engagements","promoted impressions","promoted engagements","promoted engagement rate","promoted retweets","promoted replies","promoted likes","promoted user profile clicks","promoted url clicks","promoted hashtag clicks","promoted detail expands","promoted permalink clicks","promoted app opens","promoted app installs","promoted follows","promoted email tweet","promoted dial phone","promoted media views","promoted media engagements"

How about some sample tweets?
Well, I mean, they're tweets. Here's some examples:

```
This is a tweet with zero hashtags.
@somename this is a reply with #one hashtag.
This is a tweet with two #hashtags, one that has #punctuation attached.
```

Comment: can you post a sample of the content of a few `Tweet Text` properties?

Comment: Added a few fake tweets. Real data has 0-6 hashtags, but common will be <4.

Comment: thanks ... i used your sample data in a demo of how to pull out the hashtags items. here's hoping it works as needed for you ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lee for giving me a couple of ideas.

It feels a little duct tape/bailing wire, but...

```bsh
Remove-Item -path .\merged\merged.csv
$InputFiles = Get-Item "*.csv"
$OldString  = '"-"'
$NewString  = '""'
$InputFiles | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv .\merged\merged.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

$dataset = Import-Csv ".\merged\merged.csv"
$dataset | ForEach-Object {
        $HashTagOut = ''
        $HashTagList = $_.'Tweet Text'.Split(' ') -match '#'
        foreach ($Hashtag in $HashTagList)
        {
            if ($Hashtag -match '#[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            {
            $HashTagOut = $HashTagOut + $Matches[0] + ' '
            }
        }
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hashtags -Value $HashTagOut.Trim() -Force
    }

$dataset | Export-Csv ".\merged\merged.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the job ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in some text from some source
$InStuff = @'
This is a tweet with zero hashtags.
@somename this is a reply with #one hashtag.
This is a tweet with two #hashtags, one that has #punctuation attached.
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$HashTagList = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    @($IS_Item.Split(' ')) -match '#'
    }

$HashTagList
```

output ...

```
#one
#hashtags,
#punctuation
```

if you need to remove the punctuation, that can be done with a bit of fiddling. [*grin*]